# Webform submit action without postback

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a webpage in which all the server side calls are done through ajax calls without post-back. I need to implement WFFM(web forms for marketers) in the page and achieve the same functionality without post-back. I don't find much documentation regarding this. Can anyone help me with this please?? I'm new to WFFM...Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: You could try to wrap the placeholder for the WFFM form in a UpdatePanel control. Maybe that works.

Comment: @RuudvanFalier: Guess that would work but im just trying to achieve it using Ajax calls...would that be posible?? Since update panel processes the entire page the performance is hit and lot other things gets messy...!!

Comment: If you put just the WFFM placeholder in the UpdatePanel it will only process the user control for the form. I don't see any other realistic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that WFFM does not ship with any documentation or built in support for doing this, out of the box. You could try to create your own custom submit button that submits the form via AJAX, which would be making a custom control. WFFM has some documentation about this, but it is limited and, IMHO, far from sufficient.

Web Forms for Marketers does not have the most verbose documentation, which is unfortunate because modifying anything related to WFFM is, IMHO, not a particularly fun time - mostly because of the investigation and ramp-up time. Start by perusing the documentation, and then decompile and dive right into the two WFFM DLLs. There you will find far more information than you will in the documentation for how to create a custom WFFM control.

As stated in Ruud's comment, the UpdatePanel control is your best bet here. The [UpdatePanel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx) actually IS an AJAX control - it is meant to update/submit parts of the page using AJAX. If you are worried about performance from that standpoint, I guess I am at a loss as to why you are making all server-side calls through AJAX. Even asynchronously you are going to have a serious degradation of performance on both the front and back end if you are doing a lot of AJAX processing. My suggestion is that when you dive into the WFFM DLLs, have a look at all of the processing that you are going to be waiting for with your AJAX call, and then make your decision on how to proceed from there.